# How can I loop to get counts from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to derive a table with counts from multiple tables.  The tables are not on my schema.  The table names on the schema that I am interested in all start with 'STAF_' and end with '_TS'.  The criteria i am looking for is where SEP = 'MO'.  So for example, the query in its base form is:

```
select area, count(SEP) areacount
from mous.STAF_0001_TS
where SEP = 'MO'
group by area;
```

I have about 1000 tables that i'd like to do this for.

Ultimatly, I'd like the output to be a table on my schema that looks like the following:

```
 area| areacount
 0001|  3
 0002|  7
 0003|  438
```

Thank you.

Comment: Don't store calculated data like that. Create a view instead, will always be up to date!

Comment: A view would be fine also. Just wanted to know how to get the output i needed.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want output from a more or less unknown set of tables?

Comment: yes, i estimate the count of tables to be around 1k, but im not sure. Its mainly all the tables in the mous schema that have the structure STAF_0001_TS, where the 0001 part is variable.

Comment: Why do you have all those tables? (Seems like a horrible db design.)

Answer (score 1):

As a first step I'd write an SQL query that generates an SQL query:

```
SELECT 'SELECT area, count(*) FROM '||c.table_name||'UNION ALL' as run_me
FROM all_tables c
WHERE c.table_name LIKE 'STAF\_%\_MS' escape '\'
```

Running this will produce an output that is another SQL query. Copy the result text out of your results grid and paste it back into your query pane. Delete the final UNION ALL and run it

Once you dig how to write an SQL query that generate an SQL query, you can look at turning it into a view, or creating a dynamic query in a string.

Gotta say, this is a horrible way to store data; you'd be better off using ONE table with an extra column containing whatever is in xxx of STAF_xxx_MS right now

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12c, you can embed a `FUNCTION` that will query the number of rows in any given table.  Then you can use that function in your main query.  Here is an example:

```
WITH FUNCTION cnt ( p_owner VARCHAR2, p_table_name VARCHAR2 ) RETURN NUMBER IS
  l_cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT count(*) INTO :cnt FROM ' || p_owner || '.' || p_table_name INTO l_cnt;
  RETURN l_cnt;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  RETURN NULL;  -- This will happen for entries in ALL_TABLES that are not directly accessible (e.g., IOT overflow tables)
END cnt;
SELECT t.owner, t.table_name, cnt(t.owner, t.table_name)
FROM all_tables t
where t.table_Name like 'STAF\_%\_MS' escape '\';
```